# calling fftw in multi thread program

Tags: c++, multithreading, fftw

I want to use fftw3 in threads. But the code pasted at http://codepad.org/lIjdGF5z causes "double free or corruption" error. How to call fftw3 routines in threads properly. Thanks! You can compile the code through command "g++ test.cpp -lfftw3_threads -lfftw3 -lboost_thread"

Comment: You shouldn't be creating and destroying a plan every time you do an FFT. Just do it once.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the call to `fftw_plan_dft_2d` is not reentrant, meaning that it can't be called in multiple threads simultaneously, even if you are creating different plans.  The only fftw functions that are thread-safe are `fftw_execute` variants according to paragraph 2 of the [Thread Safety page](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Thread-safety.html#Thread-safety) of the documentation.

Additionally as Paul R. mentioned in the comments, you should only create the plan/s once at the beginning and then use them over and over.  It will be much faster.  Also, according to paragraph 3 of the Thread Safety documentation page, you can use the same plan in multiple simultaneous calls to `fftw_execute`.  So if your transforms are the same size, you will only need one plan for all the threads.

Comment: how about the program pasted at http://codepad.org/nHSAN1lJ . The thread only contains the reentrant routine of fftw

Comment: Is it working?  If not, I don't think you need to use the `fftw_plan_many_dft` interface here.  That is for if you have multiple 2D FFTs to perform in sequence with a single `fftw_execute` call.  The fact that you are calling it with `howmany == 1` means that you are still only doing one 2D transform per `fftw_execute`.  You can still just use the simpler `fftw_plan_dft_2d` interface.

Comment: How can one use the same plan in multiple simultaneous calls to `fftw_execute`? Since a plan encapsulates its input/output, won't that give you either undefined or at best identical results?

Comment: That is true for the standard `fftw_execute` call, but you can also use the "New-array execute functions" mentioned here: http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/New_002darray-Execute-Functions.html#New_002darray-Execute-Functions.  In these, as long as the data is formatted identically, you can pass in different input and output pointers to each execute call.