# "Pointer being freed was not allocated" error using cython in parallel with an external c library based on FFTW

Tags: python, c, pointers, cython, fftw

## What I'm attempting

I have a code which was previously parallelised in `python` using `multiprocess` and it worked okay (although slow and memory hungry). I've decided to try to convert it to `cython`. I'm new to `cython` and not much experience in `c`. The below example is as simplified as I can get it, and it **worked** serially, but as soon as I parallelised it, it no longer works. Due to the nature of running in parallel I've gone through all my code and turned off `gil`.

The code relies on an external C library https://github.com/astro-informatics/ssht/ (compilation instructions in the `README`) which uses `fftw` under the hood. This library has its own `cython` file which calls the same `c` function that I'm using (`ssht_core_mw_inverse_sov_sym_ss`). The function which closely resembles mine (in the `cython` file in that repo) looks like this

```
def ssht_inverse_mwss_complex(
    np.ndarray[ double complex, ndim=1, mode="c"] f_lm not None,
    int L,
    int spin
):
    cdef ssht_dl_method_t dl_method = SSHT_DL_RISBO
    f_mwss_c = np.empty([L+1,2*L,], dtype=complex)
    ssht_core_mw_inverse_sov_sym_ss(
        <double complex*> np.PyArray_DATA(f_mwss_c),
        <const double complex*> np.PyArray_DATA(f_lm),
        L,
        spin,
        dl_method,
        0
    )
    return f_mwss_c
```

I've essentially had to recreate this locally as I needed it without `gil`.

## The problem

When I run a script using the cython module I get a segmentation fault but the error is slightly different each time. Either there is no error for explanation, or it talks about pointer memory allocation:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7f83de8b58e0: pointer being freed was not allocated
python(21855,0x70000d333000) malloc: Double free of object 0x7f83de8b58e0
python(21855,0x70000d536000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

or it seems to be specific to `FFTW`:

```
fftw: /Users/runner/.conan/data/fftw/3.3.8/_/_/build/55f3919d9a41efc78a625ee65e5d1ea60d02b2ff/source_subfolder/kernel/planner.c:261: assertion failed: SLVNDX(slot) == slvndx
```

Looking around I've found this kind of issue https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/435 so I'm hoping that `fftw` means what I'm trying to do isn't possible (and more that I'm bad at `c`).

## What I've tried

I've tried using `free` from `libc.stdlib` but that doesn't do the trick. I'd also tried to create the arrays using `cython.view` arrays but struggled to make them `double complex` (which is required by the `ssht` library). I tried to get `cython` debug to work but had issues getting this to work on my mac. I've also spent 2 days banging my ahead against the wall...

## My system

I compile my extension in the usual manner `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. I'm using `python3.8.5`, `Cython==0.29.21`. I'm running on `macOS 11.0.1`.

## The code

My cython file:

```
import numpy as np
from libc.stdio cimport printf
from libc.stdlib cimport calloc, malloc
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange
from openmp cimport omp_get_thread_num

# needed to recreate without importing (for nogil)
cdef extern from "ssht/ssht.h" nogil:
    ctypedef enum ssht_dl_method_t:
        SSHT_DL_RISBO, SSHT_DL_TRAPANI
    void ssht_core_mw_inverse_sov_sym_ss(
        double complex *f,
        const double complex *flm,
        int L,
        int spin,
        ssht_dl_method_t dl_method,
        int verbosity
    )

def my_cython_module(int L, int threads):
    """
    dummy function more to show that parallel loops fails
    """
    cdef int ell, tid
    with nogil, parallel(num_threads=threads):
        tid = omp_get_thread_num()
        for ell in prange(L * L, schedule="guided"):
            printf("ell: %i\n", ell)
            _ssht_inverse(L, ell)

cdef double complex * _ssht_inverse(int L, int ind) nogil:
    """
    function creates a 1D complex array flm  with zeros and a 1
    then calls c function to get 2D complex array f
    not returning anything as it's just for demonstration
    """
    cdef ssht_dl_method_t dl_method = SSHT_DL_RISBO
    cdef double complex *flm = NULL
    cdef double complex *f = NULL
    flm = <double complex *> calloc(L * L, sizeof(double complex))
    flm[ind] = 1
    f = <double complex *> malloc((L + 1) * (2 * L) * sizeof(double complex))
    ssht_core_mw_inverse_sov_sym_ss(f, flm, L, 0, dl_method, 0)
    return f
```

My `setup.py`:

```
import os
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import Extension, setup

# running on mac so need GCC instead of clang
os.environ["CC"] = "gcc-10"

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        Extension(
            "test",
            ["*.pyx"],
            extra_compile_args=["-fopenmp"],
            extra_link_args=["-fopenmp"],
            include_dirs=["/usr/local/include"],
        ),
        annotate=True,
        language_level=3,
        compiler_directives=dict(boundscheck=False, embedsignature=True),
    ),
)
```

## A minimal working example in python using parallelism

The following works (`pip install pyssht`) and works successfully in parallel. So problem seems to be with `c`/`cython`

```
# the cython wrapper from the external library
from pyssht import ssht_inverse_mwss_complex
import numpy as np
from multiprocess import Pool

def my_python_implementation(L, threads):
    """
    the python equivalent in parallel
    """
    def func(chunk):
        """
        deals with each chunk
        """
        for ell in chunk:
            print(f"ell: {ell}")
            flm = np.zeros(L * L, dtype=np.complex_)
            flm[ell] = 1
            ssht_inverse_mwss_complex(flm, L, 0)

    chunks = np.array_split(np.arange(L * L), threads)
    with Pool(processes=threads) as p:
        p.map(func, chunks)
```

## Thanks in advance!

Seeing as I was able to run it in parallel in python I'm really hoping that it can be done.

Comment: nicely written question

Comment: I'm not completely confident about this, but it might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318933/calling-fftw-in-multi-thread-program. Essentially some bits of fftw don't appear to like being called in parallel. See http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_3.html#SEC46 for some details

Comment: @DavidW thanks hadn't seen that one. I added to my question `A minimal working example in python using parallelism`, if this is the case why can I do it in `python`?

Comment: Because multiprocessing is a lot more separate than multithreading. They're running in separate address spaces with no shared data that needs coordination (with very limited coordination at the end to bring all the results together). This both the reason that it works, and also the reason that it isn't a very satisfactory solution (processes are slow to start, etc)

Comment: Ah I get you. So looks like it may not be possible then...

Comment: My guess is that it might be possible, but it probably can't be done at the Cython/Python level. I'd think you'd need to modify the C code within ssht (to force the iffy bits of fftw to run single threaded). One question is "how long does each iteration take in your multiprocessing version?" - if it's more than ~0.5s then the overhead of multiprocessing may be small compared to the calculation so you probably won't notice too much speedup (time cutoff is a complete guess but probably isn't hugely out)

Comment: so that actual call to `c` above is very quick but in reality I have several nested loops (basically filling up a L^2 * L^2 array). So I do benefit a lot from parallelism. I'm hesitant to modify the `ssht` code itself as it's been used successfully thus far and I'm well out of my comfort zone

Comment: If possible try to parallelize the outermost loop. If you can make the parallel chunks as big as possible then your multiprocessing solution should end up pretty good. (I don't think I have any more advice on this)

Comment: my `multiprocessing` isn't too bad considering but for `L=128` (minimum desired resolution) it does take a long time. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @DavidW pointed out that I'm running issues due to the fact that `FFTW` can't be run multithreaded (but works in python with `multiprocessing`). The problem is related to the external code I'm using which relies on `FFTW`. I've raised an issue to see if we can force the `FFTW` bits to be single threaded https://github.com/astro-informatics/ssht/issues/44